# How to do release handling for R projects

Tags: r, release

I have an project in R (set of codes written in R) which uses several R libraries. Everytime when I want to deploy my project in a new machine, all the R libraries have to be setup from scratch - by installing from CRAN (including the dependencies for libraries). Libraries are constantly upgraded by the CRAN community and sometimes when I have to setup things in a new machine, some R  libraries does not get installed due to some dependencies failure.

**Any recommendations/help on how to do release handling with R projects?**

Comment: Could please clarify? Try to be as specific as possible. Also showing what you have tried may help. Furthermore, check out the `checkpoint` package.

Comment: Maybe try [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [mran](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/timemachine/), provided by Revolution R/Microsoft. It enables you to load old versions of packages by referencing a backdated mirror of CRAN. This should mitigate your issue with code rot.